# Any pitfalls for replicating MySQL to a remote server

Tags: mysql, replication

Are there any pitfalls or gotchas for replicating (master->slave) MySQL DB to a remote server about 100ms ping away?

Comment: Yes, just one, to make it asynchronous and not synchronous.

Comment: Pointers out of sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tons depending on what you want to do and what features you are using. The documentation points out most common things you should be aware of; especially the "features and issues" section.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html